# Data Cleaning using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have a non-uniform dataset I want to eliminate words starting with the $ symbol and in place of the deleted word I want to keep next word after deleted word. How to approach this problem.

DAY1          APPLE  BANANA  POTATO  $aarb   GRAPES  PINEAPPLE

---

DAY2          APPLE  BANANA  $aarb   POTATO  GRAPES  PINEAPPLE

---

DAY3          APPLE  BANANA  $aarb   POTATO  GRAPES

Ex: If I remove $aarb from the first row the next word GRAPES must take the place of $aarb and PINEAPPLE must take the place of GRAPES.

Please, anyone, help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a CSV file? Or an excel file?

Comment: It's a CSV file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please explain your problem in detail, with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. We need to know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import re

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        r = re.compile('[^$]')
        newlist = list(filter(r.match,row))
        print(newlist)
```

Feel free to substitute with whatever you want to do with `print(newlist)`, you can write to file or output it to somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, the problem is in my dataset I have a lot of different types of words starting with the $ symbol. How to remove them all at once and rearrange the data.

Comment: @AthotaSrinivas I have edited it, it should work now. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It's not working, it is still showing the $ symbol words

Comment: I just tested it with $words in rows. Could you show me some examples which it doesn't work?

Comment: WSSS_AYPY,WSSS,SUNVA,SUSIn,DOSNO,VENPA,$abAH,ATKAX,$abAI,BARRA,PY,AYPY                                                                                           this is the small part of  data I have, could you please check on this data

Comment: Oops! sorry it was a typo in code. Check the update again.

Comment: No problem, Then please mark the answer too. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to convert that list into csv file but I am getting only one row at the end, how to get all the rows

Comment: You need to write inside the loop so you get all rows to csv. [Code](https://pastebin.com/EhfFvCiP)

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'                                                        It's showing error like above at last line of the code

Comment: Got it in the code you provided, you opened the write-file with the binary mode that's why it's giving an error at the last line.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing, I want to concatenate the data in the CSV file. I want output like below                                                                                        WSSS_AYPY;WSSS SUNVA SUSIn DOSNO VENPA ATKAX BARRA AYPY;;;

Comment: @AthotaSrinivas Thats a different topic haha. You should try finding it online, there are a lot of resources.